# Repeat a string based on a column - BigQuery/SQL Standard

Tags: google-bigquery, sql

It should be very easy, but I am stucked in this.

It is simple as the image, but I have a column named "category" and once the row has a category, I want this value repeated for 'n' times, let's say 10 times (or whatever I want), in a new column.

I've tried to use `FIRST_VALUE()`, but there is no pattern about when this category will appear, so most of times I have 'null' as a repetition.

I've seen `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PRECEDING AND FOLLOWING)` but I can't use a string in this, just an aggregation and I don't want to calculate, I wanna classify. I even tried using `CASE WHEN xxx category * 10`  etc, or `category + 10` but of course doesn't work.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

What I've tried:

```
WITH table1 AS( 

SELECT
date,
hour,
minute,
category, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn
FROM table1),

table2 AS(
SELECT
*,
  CASE 
  WHEN category IS NOT NULL THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END AS flag_category
FROM table1)

SELECT
*,
  CASE 
  WHEN flag_category = 1
  THEN (SELECT 
        a.category,
        FROM table2 AS a
        INNER JOIN table2 AS b
        ON a.rn = b.rn + 10)
  ELSE '-'
  END AS category_repetition

FROM table2
```

[image explication here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UuFQ.png)

```
W   H   A   T      I     H  A   V  E    WHAT     I     WANT
date       hour minute  qty category    category_repetition
20210412    0    0       2  null              null
20210412    0    1       0  null              null
20210412    0    2       6  null              null
20210412    0    3       7  null              null
20210412    0    4       7  null              null
20210412    0    5       6  null              null  
20210412    0    6       3  null              null
20210412    0    7       8  null              null
20210412    0    8       4  null              null
20210412    0    9       3  category A      category A
20210412    0   10       4  null            category A
20210412    0   11       0  null            category A
20210412    0   12       5  null            category A
20210412    0   13       2  null            category A
20210412    0   14       3  null            category A
20210412    0   15       3  null            category A
20210412    0   16       4  null            category A
20210412    0   17       3  null            category A
20210412    0   18       5  null            category A
20210412    0   19       4  null            category A
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `last_value(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*,
       last_value(category ignore nulls) over (order by date, hour, minute) as category_repetition
from t;
```

I'm not sure what the "10" means in the question.  This should produce the data that you want, based on the sample data and results.

Comment: Hi, Gordon!! Amazing, it worked! Thanks again for your help. If I wanted to define how many times I want that this value repeats, is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Beside that, do you have any advice about online courses, websites or books that I can improve SQL standard? My main goal is about analytics skills, as you can see. Thanks!

Comment: @julius.86 . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a further refinement of the question, you should ask a *new* question.